# Extending an interface in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, interface, typescript

In JavaScript, it is straight-forwardd to add functions and members to the `prototype` of any type. I'm trying to achieve the same in TypeScript as follows:

```
interface Date
{
    Minimum: Date;
}

Date.prototype.Minimum = function () { return (new Date()); }
```

This produces the following error:

```
Type '() => Date' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
Property 'toDateString' is missing in type '() => Date'.
```

Considering TS is strongly-types, how could we achieve this?

Since I'm writing a custom utility library in TS, I'd rather not resort to JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have it like this:

```
interface Date
{
    Minimum(): Date;
}

(<any>Date.prototype).Minimum = function () { return (new Date()); }

let d = new Date();
console.log(d.Minimum());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that the assertion to `any` is not necessary.

Answer (score 26):

Interfaces don't get transpiled to JS, they're just there for defining types.

You could create a new interface that would inherit from the first:

```
interface IExtendedDate extends Date {
    Minimum: () => Date;
}
```

But for the actual implementations you will need to define a *class*. For example:

```
class ExtendedDate implements IExtendedDate {
    public Minimum(): Date {
        return (new ExtendedDate());
    }
}
```

However note that you can do all this without an interface.

Comment: Upvoted. In my view this is better than messing with the prototype of a buit-in object, even though JS let's you do it.